# Push-button on/off controller for ESP32

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, esp32, toggle-switch

I am trying to design a circuit to turn on/off the ESP32. When I press the button, the ESP32 will start and will not turn off until I press the button again.

Will this circuit work for this problem?

[image]

Comment: There already are many push-on, push-off switches. (Or simple, ON/OFF switches.) Why wouldn't one of those work for this? Why does it need to be a momentary?

Comment: @jonk I wanted to make it like a phone's power button

Comment: Short touch to turn on, long hold to turn off? Without an MCU? If so, you can look [at this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/559374/38098). And get an idea of how difficult it is if you aren't using an MCU in the loop.

Comment: @jonk Yes I will use MCU (ESP32)