# Circuit for converting a long button-push event to a short button-push event

Tags: switches

I have an existing circuit (runs on 12V), which I can start with a single push-button press.

I press this button sometimes accidentally which triggers unwanted starts. I would like to start this circuit with a long button press instead, like 5 seconds.

I'm a software developer, and I could write easily an Arduino app that does the job, but I believe this would be overkill for this task.

What is the name of the circuit I am looking for?

Comment: Seems to me that a software fix is the ideal choice.

Comment: What does the circuit look like? What is the turn-on trigger condition? Post schematics if possible. A simple RC low-pass filter could (or could not) work, although you need large R and C values to get the time constant into the 5 second range.

Comment: There are reset button controllers like the TPS3422.

Comment: Have you considered a mechanical solution? There are many types of switch guards available, some with hinged covers, others recess the switch.

Comment: I would call this a de-bouncer with a long time delay. An inadvertent press can be interpreted as a bounce.

Comment: Time delayed actuator is another choice.

Comment: get rid of the pushbutton switch and install a spring loaded turn knob switch

Comment: SaWo, you can also look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/559374/38098) for something similar. You really are better off with a cheap MCU (you can find some in SOT23-6 or SOIC8 that are under US$1 and are available now, not on backorder.) The MCU approach will take almost no power and you can easily write software (as you say) to adjust per your final desires. An analog circuit (such as at the above link or in answers here perhaps) can be made to work. But now you need to modify parts or the schematic for changes. Software is easier, especially with your background I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

A 12V DC, 'off-the-shelf', 'on-delay' timer would do.

[image]

When the push button switch S1 is actuated, the timer K1 'NO' contact gives the 'start' command after the set time elapses.