# 555 timer and JK flip-flop activation problem

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

I need to toggle a MOSFET after I hold a button for 3 seconds. Here is my circuit:

[image]

I have a JK flip-flop for the toggle function. When the clock pin of the JK flip-flop goes high to low, output of the flip-flop toggles. There is no problem here. The 555 timer gives a single shot signal after holding the button for 3 seconds. The problem is that when I press the button, the JK flip-flop toggles instantly though even 555 timer doesn't give an output.

My theory is that when the button is off, the 555 timer output is a floating  around 0.150 volt.  When I press the button, the output of the 555 becomes 0 volt, no longer floating and it becomes ground. The JK flip-flop therefore thinks this is a clock down and toggles the output.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a hold-for-3-seconds to turn off device kind of thing? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, i want to turn on and turn off when i hold the button 3 seconds or more.

Comment: That's probably a sot23-6 MCU then. Cheap. Easy to use. Easy to adapt, where needed. But I did [find this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/559374/330261) on this site if 555s are to be used.

Comment: You're switching the Vcc to the 555. Maybe try an RC on the /RESET input. But I don't like this circuit much.

Comment: i don't have microchip programmer, so it is not kinda viable solution. @SpehroPefhany maybe i can keep vcc of 555 timer high all the time and connect only the reset pin (with pull down) after button i will try that.

Comment: A bipolar 555 draws quite a bit of current just sitting there, so it’s inappropriate for a battery-powered device. Otherwise it might be okay.